# Extracting the value from a Pandas Dataframe column that has only a unique value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas DataFrame (df), where one column (unique_val_col) should have a unique value, what is the best the best way to extract this value (not as a list)?

So far I've used the following code:

```py
output = list(set(df[unique_val_col)))

if len(output)==1:  output = output[0]
```

Or if there is a chance for nans then change the first line to be:

```py
output = [val for val in list(set(df[unique_val_col))) if val == val]
```

The question is whether there is a more direct way, that would also reflect the fact that the column actually has only one value without needing the 'if' statement.

Comment: If the column has always the same value, can you not just take `output = df[unique_val_col].iloc[0]`?

Comment: Yes, Xavier is right. If all the rows have the same values, I would just do `output = df.loc[0, 'unique_val_col']`

Comment: Do you want to force confirmation of the assumption that `df['unique_val_col']` is in fact unique?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can't always use loc since the index might not have a 0, and even if it does, it might contain a nan. I need something robust

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to find a value that occurs only once, if that's so you could achieve it like this

```
df['unique_value_counts'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).keys()[0]
```

Comment: No, I was looking for the value that occurs throughout the column, and is the only value in the column (except perhaps for nans).